# RuntimeException SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for... Laravel 4 upload image

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4, spl, splfileobject

I work with *laravel 4 (last update)*, I create a **form** where we could **upload an image** (logo/avatar). I am on **MAC OS,** I use **sublime Text 3**, **laravel** and **MAMP Applications**. All my configuration is setting right, no running problems.

My probleme is that I have this **error** when I submit the reaching fields from my form: **RuntimeException
SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpRUJfMX**

Here's the code from my form **nameOfTheForm.blade.php**:

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('title')
Name Of My Project - EditProfile
@stop

@section('content')
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'uploadAvatar','files' => true))}}

<p>
{{Form::label('pseudo','pseudo (*): ')}}
{{Form::text('pseudo',Input::old('nom'))}}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('pseudo'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('pseudo')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>

<p>
{{Form::label('url_Avatar','Avatar: ')}}
{{Form::file('url_Avatar',Input::old('Url_Avatar'))}}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('url_Avatar'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('url_Avatar')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>

<p>
{{Form::submit('Validate your avatar')}}
</p>

{{Form::close()}}
@stop
```

Here's the code from my **controller**:

```
public function uploadAvatar() {


//*****UPLOAD FILE (on server it's an image, on the DB it's an url*****
  $file = Input::File('url_Avatar');

  //set a register path to the uploaded file
  $destinationPath = public_path().'/upload/';

  //have client extension loaded file and set a random name to the uploaded file, produce a random string of length 32 made up of alphanumeric characters [a-zA-z0-9]

  $filename = $destinationPath . '' . str_random(32) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

  $uploaded = Input::File('url_Avatar')->move($destinationPath,$filename);

//*****VALIDATORS INPUTS and RULES*****
  $inputs = Input::all();
  $rules = array(
    'pseudo' => 'required|between:1,64|unique:profile,pseudo',
    //urlAvatar is an url in database but we register as an image on the server
    'url_Avatar' => 'required|image|min:1',
  );
```

The uploaded file code works perfect, I register the file in the selected folder I want. I Have no problem with my routes (no need to show this part of the code).

But When I submit the form, I have this error:
***RuntimeException***
**SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpRUJfMX**

*error info details:*
***open:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nameOfMyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php***

```
    }
    elseif (is_array($value))
    {
        return count($value);
    }
    elseif ($value instanceof File)
    {
        return $value->getSize() / 1024;
    }
    else
```

It seems, that Laravel needs (stat - Gives information about a file), that is to say, needs to have the informations from the uploaded file, here the size, but I try this in my controller just before the line where here's $uploaded where I move the file in my selected folder:

```
//I add this line code before
$size= $file->getSize();
$uploaded=Input::File('url_Avatar')->move($destinationPath,$filename);
```

But, when I did that, I have another error: the validator doesn't r**ecognize the files as an image** et ask me to upload **a valid format**. I think I need to correct the first errors I had **(SplFileInfo::getSize())**

If you have any ideas... Thank you.

Comment: You must read the file's attributes before move it.
Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114252/runtimeexception-splfileinfogetsize-stat-failed-in-laravel/53114743

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: Laravel's Symphony source returns file size of 0 if the file size is larger than php.ini's `upload_max_filesize`.

Recommend checking your php.ini file. I'm not sure how MAMP handles php.ini but it's there if you're running Laravel. In php.ini, the upload_max_filesize may be smaller than the file you're attempting to upload. That value happened to be defaulted on my Ubuntu 12.10 VM to 2megs.

Check

`/vendor/symphony/http-foundation/Symphony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php`

and check the `getMaxFilesize()`. By default, this method grabs the `upload_max_filesize` value from your PHP.ini file on your host system.

The interesting thing about this is that if you do

```
$foo = Input::file('uploaded_file') 
var_dump($foo)
```

or

use Laravel's `die&dump dd($foo)`, then a file that's larger than php.ini's upload_max_filesize returns a size of 0.

In addition to upload_max_filesize, PHP docs also mention checking php.ini so that:

```
- post_max_size must be larger than upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size
```

Comment: I don't have my code with me for now, but tomorrow I will try this solution. Thank you to both of you for your understanding.

Comment: and so it works, MAMP has another php.ini file in htdocs folder and I can change some parameters like image size file. So I follow your steps, with your code.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size - to follow up on Ryan's comment

Answer (score 5):

I know this question has been answered quite some time ago, but I found something on the PHP website which might be useful because it actually explains why the error occurs:

> If you're using Symfony's UploadedFile,
> please be aware that if you call this method
> *after* you call @move, you will most likely get
> some obscenely untraceable error, that says:
>
> `stat failed`
>
> Which if you really think about it, it does makes sense,
> the file has been moved by Symfony, but getSize is in SplFileInfo,
> and SplFileInfo doesn't know that the file has been moved.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getsize.php#122780

Answer (score 3):

I got same error In Laravel 6x. This error is due to null value for column which was not nullable.

To resolve I just changed column to accept null after that is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem with edit columns attribute default "null" and the problem gone.