# Uncaught RuntimeException: SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed

Tags: php

I am getting the above error when trying to run the following lines of script:

```
$fileInfo = new SplFileInfo($subfile);
if ($fileInfo->getExtension() == 'brd') {
    $debug->alert_code_info($fileInfo);
    $filesize = $fileInfo->getSize();
    functionName($subfile, 'application/octet-stream', $filesize);
}
```

The getExtension function works, as I'm able to proceed to the code within the if block.  So why is getExtension() working while getSize() isn't?

Comment: How can we possibly tell you, if we can't see the SplFileInfo class with the `getSize()` method?

Comment: Here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

Comment: Seems to have something to do with the size of the file you're processing. Seems that if the file is larger than what's set in your php.ini file under `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`, it'll pop up this exception.

Comment: Something simular was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138189/runtimeexception-splfileinfogetsize-stat-failed-for-laravel-4-upload-ima Although it's Lavarel, the problem is essentialy the same.

Comment: @icecub That's only relevant if the OP is working on uploaded files (which might be the case, but we don't know). OP.. are you working on uploaded files?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Agreed. Though after doing some research on Google, it seems that's the only (known) case where this perticular exception pops up. That's why I mentioned it like that.

Comment: If you mean do I use a form to upload files, the answer is no.  This is part of an automated script that searches through a file directory and finds files meeting certain criteria (that's the $subfile) and then copying them to another folder.  Although I suppose if this fits the definition of "upload," then yes, I am.

Comment: No, that's not file upload so the above ini-settings shouldn't matter. Make sure that you pass an absolute file path to `SplFileInfo()` (like `/full/path/from/the/root/myfile.brd`). You will get that error if you're trying to stat a file that's not found.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You're right. On php.net it stated that it returns false if the file isn't found. But when I tested it on my server it indeed returns the exception and not simply false

Comment: @icecub Don't know where you saw that it returns false? This is from the [manual for SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getsize.php): _"A RuntimeException will be thrown if the file does not exist or an error occurs."_

Comment: @MagnusEriksson In the comments of [SplFileInfo:getSize](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getsize.php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson But ye, my mistake. I shouldn't have relied on the comments. So I stand corrected :)

Comment: If it's that the file isn't found, shouldn't it be that getExtension() should throw an exception as well?  It seems to be finding the file, just not finding the size of the file.