# RuntimeException SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, postgresql

I am new to laravel. I try to upload an image, but I get an error in getClientsize. I try to check solution in google. I follow it edit the post_max_size and uploaded_max_size file but it still not function for me.
Anyone can help to solve this issue. I attached the code below.

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\file;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class testing extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new file;
        $user->title = Input::get('name');
        if(Input::hasFile('image')){
            $file=Input::file('image');
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $file);
            $user->name=$file->getClientoriginalName();
            $user->size=$file->getClientsize();
            $user->type=$file->getClientMimeType();
        }
        $user->save();
        return "data saved";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Probable reason is because file has been moved from tmp to its assigned path, it does not exist anymore. So reading the file size from the tmp file is invalid operation.

Possible solution: read the file size before moving the file. Worked for me.

```
if ($req->hasFile('uploadedFile')) 
{
    $file = $req->file('uploadedFile');
    $filesize = $file->getSize();
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    if ($file->move('upload/', $filename))
    {
        $insert = DB::table('table')->insert(["filename" =>$filename,
                                             "size"      =>$filesize]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
getClientsize() -> getClientSize()
```

But if it doesn't help - your problem not in your php file, but in php config file. By default you can upload 2M (megabyte) file.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

But you can change it here:

add line in .htaccess:

> php_value upload_max_filesize 50M

or Ubuntu:

> /etc/php/7.1(your version)/apache2/php.ini (find upload_max_filesize,
>   and override it)

or

> /etc/php/php.ini

After editing file - reboot apache

Comment: tq for your comment..but it not work..i cannot add upload_max_filesize in .htaccess file..i try to add but it block my xampp from running.

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: @SitiAsna I updated my answer for htaccess. Sorry, it was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

By reading documentation of laravel 6.* and php 7.3 you can see for uploading file you can use `store` method.
if you want to storing file in public or public_html at first run `php artisan vendor:publish` and in `config->filesystems.php` define new disks for example with name of `public_local` and set the root of this disk to public address:

```
'public_local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
        ],
```

then in order to store file in this disk you can use store method that set a unique name for your file or use storeas with custom name:
with store method:

```
$path = $request->file('image_url')->store($imagePath, 'public_local');
```

```
$path = $request->file('image_url')->storeAs($imagePath, 'custom_name', 'public_local');
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost 8 hours to figure out the cause finally, I found that:

This error arising if you **upload the file in the controller** (using $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $file);)  and again if you use 'use HasMediaTrait' trait in the model.

**Reason:**
In controller file already uploaded using the statement '$file->move(public_path().'/images/', $file);'
Again if you use the 'use HasMediaTrait' trait in model, system trying to upload the file again then results this error.

**Solution:**
If you upload in the controller, no need to use 'use HasMediaTrait' trait the model, otherwise just **remove the file upload logic in the controller and just use trait (use HasMediaTrait) in the model**.

I hope this gives more insight.

- Adi